# What is the principle behind "circuit total limitation" (CTL) for electrical panels?

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

Contemporary electrical panels/loadcenters limit the number of tandem circuit breakers that can be used. Is this because areas of the underlying panel bus bars can overheat despite all of the individual breakers (including the main) operating below their rated trip current? Or is it because of the risk of a neutral slot being used by more than one circuit? Both? Something else?

Answer (score 2):

It is to limit the total number of circuits, and so the total load on the bus etc.  It doesn't have anything to do with the neutrals.

Answer (score 2):

Circuit Total Limitations comes from a requirement way back in the 1960's where the NEC required panel board manufactures to limit the total number of circuit breakers a panel could contain.

The principle was probably safety and prevention of fire due to the advent of tandem breakers possibility of being overused beyond the panel boards listed capacity.

Comment: *Kris, I think that was 1968.

Comment: In the days before silicon, when no load existed below about 100W.